# Getting Ajax parameter from inside Java servlet

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json, servlets

my data:

```
var test = {cars : []};

var cars = []
cars.push({
    "name" : "Ford",
    "year" : "2000"
});

    cars.push({
    "name" : "Audi",
    "year" : "2002"
});

test.cars = cars;   

var json = JSON.stringify(test);

$.get('/myservlet/', json, function(data) { // also tried .getJSON , .post
            alert('Success');                               
})
```

In Java I get the "json" variable as parameter key, but no value.

```
public void doPost(...) // TRIED BOTH
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, ServletException {           
    for(Object a : req.getParameterMap().keySet()) {
        System.out.println(a + " - " + req.getParameter((String)a));
    }
//prints out
{"cars":[{"name":"Ford","year":"30"},{"name":"Audi","year":"2002"}]} -
```

This is unusable result, because the key is always changing, and is ridiculous to for-loop the params everytime. I need to have a specific key : `req.getParameter("cars")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
$.get('/myservlet/', 'cars='+ json, function(data) { // also tried .getJSON , .post
        alert('Success');
```

Comment: This way you still end up with a stringified JSON object as request parameter value in the server side which you'd have to manually parse with a JSON parser, which doesn't make the service exactly reuseable.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have stringified the JSON at all. The whole JSON object `test` is supposed to be treated as the request parameter map. Just pass the JSON object unmodified.

```
$.get('/myservlet/', test, function(data) {
    // ...
});
```

This way it's available in the servlet as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
    String name = request.getParameter("cars[" + i + "][name]");
    if (name == null) break;
    String year = request.getParameter("cars[" + i + "][year]");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Getting a map entry with key and value, both `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

**Update**
Your question could be possible duplicate of 
[READ JSON String in servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338943/read-json-string-in-servlet)

**Previous answer**

I assume you are trying to post JSON to the servlet, if thats the case read on.

You would have to check for request body instead of request parameter. Something like

```
BufferedReader buff = req.getReader();
```

Check if this works for you

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, ServletException {
  BufferedReader buff = req.getReader();
  char[] buf = new char[4 * 1024]; // 4 KB char buffer
  int len;
  while ((len = reader.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1) {
   out.write(buf, 0, len);
  }
}
```

Note that I have checked the above code for syntax errors. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Your "previous answer" makes no utter sense. The parameters are in case of a HTTP GET request not sent in request body at all, but instead in request URL. With only posting a link to the dupe you're in no way explaining OP's concrete problem.

Comment: @BalusC nor does your comment make any sense and falls under same category as my answer. I have clearly said that "I assume you are trying to POST". I was unclear what the OP is asking. In code comments he has mentioned that he has tried both POST and GET. The mistake in my code snippet is that I should have it doPost instead of doGet. Thanks for your bright comment.