# SOAP web service "How to accept JSON payload in servlet"

Tags: json, web-services, soap

I am new to web service i need to create a controller servlet which accepts JSON request with payload , read values from payload and then call a SOAP web service .

I am stucking on the part "how to accept(read) JSON request with payload in servlet".

I have a request URL and payload as well.

Sample payload is below.

```
{
    "relationshipid":"AR0690",
    "relationshipkey":"100005780",
    "customeridname":"MBR_ENTTY_E_LEGAL_NM_1000023393",
    "customerid":"",
    "membernameid":"AM02981",
    "createdon":"",
    "modifiedon":"",
    "draft":"05f15226-c3cb-e411-8be4-0059073ae",
    "namestring":"",
    "estimatedclosedate":"2015-04-02T01:00:00",
    "Pol_lifetimecnr":"0"
}
```

Any possible help is really appreciated.

Comment: this answer might be helpful for you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338943/read-json-string-in-servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338943/read-json-string-in-servlet)

Comment: i am using below code inside doPost method to read the json string in servlet.