# how to iterate json on servlet

Tags: java, json, ajax

i have json like

```
{
"condition": "AND",
"rules": [{
    "id": "BirthDate",
    "field": "BirthDate",
    "type": "date",
    "input": "text",
    "operator": "equal",
    "value": "2016/04/13"
}]}
```

i just want to iterate it on servlet for that i create

```
public String getRuleList(){
    String ruleList=this.get("rules");
    return ruleList;
}
public String getcondition(){
    return this.get("condition");
}
```

as getter setter when i send this json without using JSON.stringify i got the value of condition but unable to fetch rules.By using JSON.stringify i unable to fetch anything. please help..

Answer (score 0):

`rules` is JSONArray and simple get returns an object. Try to get it with the json libraries custom method.
If you are using `org.json` try this

`this.getJSONArray('rules')`

Try to provide some more information such as the json library you are using, the output you got for `this.get('rules')` and how is `this` initialized for a much better answer

Comment: this.get('rules') gives me null

Comment: my ajax call is like `var url = location.protocol + "//" + location.host +appContext+"?command=QueryBuilderServlet&action=getQueryJson";
   $.ajax({
      url:url,
       type: "POST",  
       data:JSON.stringify(result),
       dataType:'json',
       contentType : 'application/json'
   });`

Comment: refer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338943/read-json-string-in-servlet)

Answer (score 0):

To solve above problem i do

`result =JSON.stringify(result);
      var json = JSON.parse(result);
      var queryData={
              rules:JSON.stringify(json.rules),
              condition:JSON.stringify(json.condition)
      };
      console.log("result"+JSON.stringify(result));
      if (!$.isEmptyObject(result)) {
            var url = location.protocol + "//" + location.host +appContext+"?command=QueryBuilderServlet&action=getQueryJson";
          $.ajax({
                 url:url,
                 type: "POST",

                 data:queryData,
                 dataType:'json',
          });`
thanks a lot for your help